# Why does ViewPager need to specify height manually?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have **NestedScrollView** containing CardView,TabLayout and ViewPager. ViewPager is not showing the contents on Tabs if i specify android:layout_height either match_parent or wrap_content (Only tab names are visible). It only works when i specify the value in dp

**My XML Layout as below.**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/DescriptionTv"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Post description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    android:id="@+id/TabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/Viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"/>  // I want to avoid specifying values but not working
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How do i avoid specifying android:layout_height in numbers for ViewPager to match it to screen as Normal TabLayout? Please help

I have tried to add my TabLayout inside the ViewPager but not working (Both becomes invisible)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match_parent` and have a `View` inside the `ViewPager` with size `math_parent`.

Like:

```xml
<ViewPager ...layout_height="match_parent">
   <View android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ViewPager>
```

Comment: Can you please share a xml code? because i tried most of the solutions which are not working for me.

Comment: You can check the edited, sometime `ViewPager` work not correctly with children view.

Comment: I have applied your solution. I can see only tab names. my fragment is not visible.

Comment: Im not sure the exact problem but have you considered using a constraint layout? This layout would allow you to specify 0dp on both width and height of your view pager, should you constrain it correctly inside a constraint layout

Comment: Oh i have missed, please set `View` to `android:visibility="invisible"`.